# How to apply jQuery function .one() to element through attribute 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear an input field when it's clicked, but only the first time you click. With jQuery, you can achieve it like this: putting the following snippet anywhere in the document (assuming the element with id=`inputf` has already been loaded):

```
$('#inputf').one("click", function() {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

As you can see in the above snippet, the input field must have `id` attribute with value `inputf`.
But is there a way to move that snippet to the `onclick` attribute of the input field, like

```
<input type="text" onclick="$(this)....val('')" />
```

? It looks like I can't use the function `.one()`, because that function needs a string containing one or more JavaScript event types. But I just want `.one()` to be executed each time it is called, without specifying one or more event types.

Comment: Using JavaScript code inside your HTML tags is discouraged anyway, because it's always a good idea to keep your script (and styles) completely separated where it's easy to find. But no, you can't use `.one` this way because it's a jQuery method, not a JavaScript event. It doesn't appear you can even use `.off` to remove the `onclick` handler, since that only removes events that were added using `.on`.

Comment: Maybe if you told us what you were ultimately trying to acomplish, we could help you find the right method to use...

Comment: You're doing it the preferred/correct/easiest/smartest way in your first example.  Don't downgrade to mixed markup/logic.  Whatever reasons you have for trying to do this will be outweighed by the positives of maintaining code separation.

Comment: Thank you guys. I know it's better to separate that part, but there are situations where you are forced to attach the code to an element itself. (I don't like inline Javascript code either. ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only posting this since you requested, I don't advocate inline handlers.

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.onclick = null; this.value = ''; " />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aUmNK/

Comment: How does this answer the question?  This strips the onclick handler and alerts the value.  This won't remove text in the input field at all.

Comment: @XyanEwing The point is for it to be the equivalent of `.one()`. whatever the alert code is, is meant to be any code you like, like clear the element. Clearing the element code (`$(this)....val('')`), was already in the OP.

Comment: @XyanEwing, ok now it's code you can directly copy paste and never learn anything. happy ? :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onclick="if(flagCount === 0){this.value='';flagCount++;}" />
```

declare the `var flagCount = 0` as global variable in the `script` tag in `head`.

Comment: If you have to do it this way, this is the way to do it. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it for all text input fields, you could do:

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    $(this).one("click", function() {$(this).val = "";});
});
```

...or you can refine the selector to get every input field in a particular div for example:

```
$("#divId input[type=text]")
```

Comment: ...or just `$("input[type=text]").one("click", function() { $(this).val(""); });` :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do a event like `one` on the element tag. Just do something like this:

```
<input onclick="function(event) { /* do something */ this.onclick = function(){}; }" />
```

Your function will be executed only the first time, then a new void function will be attached to the onclick event callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your own simple jQuery plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.clearOnce = function() {

  this.one("click", function() {
    $(this).val("");
  });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

After this you can:

```
<input type="text" onclick="$(this).clearOnce();" />
```

Wrote in 3 min, not tested ;-)